# How can I use foreach loop to get each slider to slid like https://newyork.craigslist.org/search/fua

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use foreach loop to make my slider work as example below since am querying my image from database. please how can i achieve this? looking @ https://newyork.craigslist.org/search/fua  as case study

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250">
  <meta name="generator" content="PSPad editor, www.pspad.com">
  
  
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
     <!-- BEGIN PRODUCTS -->
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
      <span class="thumbnail">
        <div id="carousel-example-gener" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false" >
      

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/500x400&text=1"  alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/500x400&text=2" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/500x400&text=3" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/500x400&text=4"  alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/500x400&text=5" alt="...">
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-gener" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-gener" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
         <h4>Product Tittle</h4>
         <div class="ratings">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
                </div>
         <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
         <hr class="line">
         <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
           <p class="price">$29,90</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
           <button class="btn btn-success right" > BUY ITEM</button>
          </div>
          
         </div>
      </span>
    </div>
       <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
      <span class="thumbnail">
        <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false" >
      

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/500x400&text=1"  alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/500x400&text=2" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/500x400&text=3" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/500x400&text=4"  alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/500x400&text=5" alt="...">
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
         <h4>Product Tittle</h4>
         <div class="ratings">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
                </div>
         <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
         <hr class="line">
         <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
           <p class="price">$29,90</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
           <button class="btn btn-success right" > BUY ITEM</button>
          </div>
          
         </div>
      </span>
    </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
      <span class="thumbnail">
        <div id="carousel-example-generic3" class="carousel slide"  data-interval="false" >
      

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/500x400&text=1"  alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/500x400&text=2" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/500x400&text=3" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/500x400&text=4"  alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/500x400&text=5" alt="...">
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic3" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic3" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
         <h4>Product Tittle</h4>
         <div class="ratings">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
                </div>
         <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
         <hr class="line">
         <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
           <p class="price">$29,90</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
           <button class="btn btn-success right" > BUY ITEM</button>
          </div>
          
         </div>
      </span>
    </div>
           <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
      <span class="thumbnail">
        <div id="carousel-example-generic4" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false" >
      

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
       <div class="item active">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/500x400&text=1"  alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/500x400&text=2" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/500x400&text=3" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/500x400&text=4"  alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/500x400&text=5" alt="...">
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic4" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic4" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
         <h4>Product Tittle</h4>
         <div class="ratings">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
                </div>
         <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
         <hr class="line">
         <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
           <p class="price">$29,90</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
           <button class="btn btn-success right" > BUY ITEM</button>
          </div>
          
         </div>
      </span>
    </div>
    <!-- END PRODUCTS -->
 </div>
</div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Below is the foreach loop that am trying to use but it is not giving me the same result. only the first frame is sliding when navigation button is clicked. please help

```html
<!-- BEGIN PRODUCTS -->
    
          <?php 
        // foreach image.... display image
        foreach($images as $image){
         
           
      ?>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
      <span class="thumbnail">
      <?php 
     echo "<img class='img display_images img-thumbnail'  src='../uploads/{$image['image1']}' alt='{$image['company']}' style='width:400px; height:250px;'>"; 
     
     echo "<img class='img display_images img-thumbnail'  src='../uploads/{$image['image2']}' alt='{$image['company']}' style='width:400px; height:250px;'>";
     
     echo "<img class='img display_images img-thumbnail'  src='../uploads/{$image['image3']}' alt='{$image['company']}' style='width:400px; height:250px;'>";
     
      echo "<img class='img display_images img-thumbnail'  src='../uploads/{$image['image4']}' alt='{$image['company']}' style='width:400px; height:250px;'>";
      
       echo "<img class='img display_images img-thumbnail'  src='../uploads/{$image['image5']}' alt='{$image['company']}' style='width:400px; height:250px;'>";
      
      
      ?>
         <h4><?php echo $image["company"]; ?></h4>
         <p><?php echo $image["description"]; ?> </p>
         <p><b>EMAIL:</b> <a href="#"><?php echo $image["email"]; ?></a></p>
         <hr class="line">
         <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
           <p class="price">$29,90</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
           <button class="btn btn-success right" > BUY ITEM</button>
          </div>
          
         </div>
         
      </span>
    </div>
 
    <?php
        }
    ?>
  
<!-- END PRODUCTS -->
```

Comment: u should post what you had try

Comment: @bxN5 is right. Question itself is very generic... You can either render images directly to the HTML DOM from PHP, or you can create javascript array of image URLs and then render it dynamically to the HTML DOM with javascript and after that init the slider.

Answer (score 0):

First write select query to fetch images from database then loop through images.

```
foreach($images as $slider_image)
{
    <div class="item">
      <img src="<?php echo $slider_image; ?>" width="500" height="400" alt="...">
    </div>
}
```

Hope this helps.